# Issue with getting duration attribute of an audio file when cache is empty

Tags: jquery, html, audio, mp3, metadata

I have a problem with getting the metadata of an audio/mpeg (mp3).

For example, I'm using JS to get the duration of the audio file and when the cache is empty the duration value returns "Infinity" (NaN).

I have tried with the events/attributes preload and onloadedmetadata and always when the cache is empty I can't get the duration and other properties of an audio.

Note: The problem is only when I clean the cache (or when the visitors comes first time to the page).

```
    audioElement = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3');
    console.log(audioElement);
    audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    var duration = audioElement.duration;
    console.log( duration );
    });
```

Comment: If the duration is not in the metadata, maybe you can add some more listeners and work out when it is available.

Comment: I've currently got the same problem, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is because your media is streaming?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

> duration Read only double
>   The length of the media in seconds, or zero if no media data is available.  If the media   data is available but the length is unknown, this value is NaN.  *If the media is streamed and has no predefined length, the value is Inf*.

Answer (score 0):

```
audioElement = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3');
    console.log(audioElement);
    audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    var duration = audioElement.duration;
    console.log( duration );
});
```