# Possible to get the playedDuration from buffer/audioContext

Tags: html5-audio

If I'm using the AudioContext and AudioBuffers to play a sound as described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/). Is it possible to get the playedDuration somehow? playedDuration being the duration of time that has already been played on this sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can get duration from the [audio metadata](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio). Example on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058178/issue-with-getting-duration-attribute-of-an-audio-file-when-cache-is-empty):

```
audioElement = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3');
    console.log(audioElement);
    audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    var duration = audioElement.duration;
    console.log( duration );
});
```